# Nginx Serve php to only one location

Tags: nginx, php

I have three web applications in three different locations on my nginx.

/ => .NET Core Application (ERROR)

/painel => .NET Core Application (OK)

/forum => Forum PHP (IPB) (OK)

The painel and forum routes work without problems, but I can't access my root application. Probably why my php configuration for the localization / forum is changing the behavior of my root application.

Here's my nginx code:

```
server {
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 20M;

location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /painel {
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location ^~ /forum {
    alias   /home/forum;
    index  index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
}
```

Note:

When i try to access root application instead of entering the page, the navigator download this file:

[image: Fault]

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Have you restarted nginx?

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -T`.